QEMU VM unable to access (private) subnet on the host
My laptop is running Ubuntu 24.04. I installed qemu and created a VM that also runs Ubuntu 24.04. The setup works fine. Then I connected a Raspberry Pi to the laptop via Ethernet cable (no router involved). This created another subnet (10.42.0.0/24), where the laptop's IP is 10.42.0.1, and Pi's IP is 10.42.0.4.
I can ping Pi (10.42.0.4) from my laptop (the host 10.42.0.1), and I can ping my laptop from Pi as well. But the VM can't reach Pi (got "Destination Port Unreachable" when ping Pi from VM), And Pi can't reach the VM either.
The Pi -> VM path is blocked by the FORWARD chain of the iptables. I can fix it by adjusting the FORWARD chain. But I can't figure out how to allow VM -> Pi? I don't think it is blocked by the iptables, because the reject rules were not hit (counts are all 0).
Routing table on the Qemu host:
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.20.10.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno2
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     600    0        0 wlo1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
$ 

FORWARD chain on the Qemu host:
$ sudo iptables -L FORWARD -v
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 559 packets, 45927 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  559 45927 LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
  559 45927 LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
  559 45927 LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
$ sudo iptables -L LIBVIRT_FWX -v
Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere            
$ sudo iptables -L LIBVIRT_FWI -v
Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr0  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
$ sudo iptables -L LIBVIRT_FWO -v
Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 any     192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
$ 

BTW, net.ipv4.ip_forward is enabled on the qemu host, and IPv6 is disabled (blocked in ip6tables).
Any hints on how to allow VM to access Pi?
Thanks.
Yongtao

to connect Pi to laptop directly, you need a special cable (crossover cable).

The connection between laptop and Pi is fine. I can ssh to Pi from the laptop. The issue is how to access Pi from the VM. I was hoping the laptop can bridge the two by IP forwarding. But... not working. :(

I found the problem. The NetworkManager created some nftables rules for the newly created subnet (10.42.0.0/24), in a table called "nm-shared-eno2". It blocked traffic from anywhere except the laptop that is directly connected to the Pi. Since this nftables table is NOT standard iptables table, the iptables command did not show it to me. That's why I missed it.
I should really stop using iptables and switch to nftables. Thanks everyone for helping.
